# Comparando indexes de um dataframe baseado em arquivo externo

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Tenho um dataset de 60 milhões de registros que, mês passado, efetuei um recorte e restaram 45 milhões. Pois bem, pensando que poderia precisar destes 15 milhões um dia, salvei o index destes registros excluídos em um `.csv` a parte.

O dia chegou e, hoje, estou tentando, sem sucesso, aplicar este arquivo `.csv` com os index sobre o arquivo de 60 milhões original para gerar um arquivo contendo apenas os registros que foram excluídos na última operação.

Como posso gerar uma nova lista booleana de indexes usando o arquivo original e passando apenas os indexes salvos no arquivo a parte como `true`? Esta é a estrutura do meu arquivo com os indexes:

```
0              38424
1               3606
2           60994093
3              23182
4              25694
```

Entre outras coisas, tentei o seguinte:

```
new_df = df[df.index == index_excluidos]
```

P.S. Já converti o `index_excluidos` para `series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabou que a resposta era mais siples do que eu imaginava: Precisa usar o `iloc`. Segue a solução completa, caso alguém chegue aqui com o mesmo problema:

```
new_df = df.iloc[index_excluidos]
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é o método isin do pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Simulando os índices dentro do csv

```
indices = [1,3,4,5,1]
```

Criando o data frame

```
coluna = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letras':coluna})
```

Mostrando o data frame

```
df
```

|  | Letras |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 5 | f |

Utilizando o isin do pandas

```
df[df['Letras'].index.isin(indices)]
```

|  | Letras |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 5 | f |

Ou simplesmente:

```
df['Letras'].index.isin(indices)
```

para retornar um array de `True` ou `False`

```
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Para casos assim o isin geralmente tem uma performance melhor.